# c-style this or shared_from_this as function parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

So the scenario is as follows: Basically there is a `MainControl`, which has a dispatcher and calls some functions. However, the dispatcher has to call some functions in `MainControl` or for example a `Monitor` class via the `MainControl`. Also the `Monitor` class should be able to access to functions from the `Dispatcher` via the `MainControl`.

The question is should I pass the `this` pointer using smart pointers as done in the `dispatcher.Init` or with C-style pointers like in `monitor.Init()`. Or is there another better way. To be clear, I know it is also possible to pass the `this` pointer using c-style reference.

```
Class MainControl : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MainControl>
{
public:
   void Init()
   {
       dispatched.Init(shared_from_this());
       monitor.Init(this);
   };
   Dispatcher &GetDispatcher() { return dispatcher;}
   Monitor &GetMonitor() { return monitor;}
   void DoSomeThing();

protected:
   Dispatcher dispatcher; 
   Monitor monitor;
};

class Dispatcher
{
public:
   void Init(shared_ptr<MainControl> ctrl)
   {
      mainCtrl = ctrl;
   };
   void DoSomethingFromMainController()
   {
      mainCtrl->DoSomething();
      mainCtrl->GetMonitor().DoSomething();
   };
   void DoSomethingElse();

protected:
   shared_ptr<MainControl> mainCtrl;
};

class Monitor
{
public:
   void Init(MainControl *ctrl)
   {
       mainCtrl = ctrl;
   }
   void DoSomethingFromDispatcher()
   {
       mainCtrl->GetDispatcher().DoSomethingElse();
   }
   void DoSomething();
protected:
   MainControl *mainCtrl;
};
```

Comment: there is no shared ownership in your example, but a memory leak :/

Comment: btw C has no `this` afaik

Comment: `A a = new A();` is invalid.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to use smart pointers or not depends on what you want to do. Sometimes it serves a purpose, but the reason to use it has to do with ownership, not how something is passed. Your example makes very little sense and thus it's not really possible to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: Edited: So basically there is a MainControl, which has a dispatcher and calls some functions. However, the dispatcher has to call some functions in MainControl or for example a Monitor class via the MainControl. Also the Monitor class should be able to acces to functions from the Dispatcher via the MainControl.

Comment: I found `shared_from_this` as usually an antipattern if used in a normal class. It makes assumptions on the storage strategy of the user of the class.

Comment: Note that `shared_from_this` is only valid if the ownership of `*this` already is shared (that is, it is already owned by at least one `shared_ptr`). You can't magically turn any old object into a shared object.

Comment: If Dispatcher lives inside MainControl, its lifetime will be no longer than that of MainControl, so I see no point in using a shared pointer. A normal pointer should always be valid, as there can be no valid Dispatcher with an invalid pointer to the outer MainControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways, as for example, don't have reference to parent at all:

```
class MainControl
{
public:
   void DoDispatcherWork() { dispatcher.DoSomethingFromMainController(*this, monitor);}
   void DoMonitorWork() { monitor.DoSomethingFromDispatcher(dispatcher); }
   void DoSomeThing();

protected:
   Dispatcher dispatcher; 
   Monitor monitor;
};

class Dispatcher
{
public:
   void DoSomethingFromMainController(MainControl& mainCtrl, Monitor& monitor)
   {
      mainCtrl.DoSomething();
      monitor.DoSomething();
   };
   void DoSomethingElse();
};

class Monitor
{
public:
   void DoSomethingFromDispatcher(Dispatcher& dispatcher)
   {
       dispatcher.DoSomethingElse();
   }
   void DoSomething();
};
```

Comment: This could work. However, when for instance the ``Dispatcher`` requires access to 10 more instances, instantiated in the ``MainController`` wouldn't ``DoSomethingFromMainController()`` become unreadable long?

Comment: Provide getters to `MainControl` is still possible, And then you have `void Dispatcher::DoSomethingFromMainController(MainControl& mainCtrl)
   {
      mainCtrl.DoSomething();
      mainCtrl.GetMonitor().DoSomething();
   };`